# What's the cost of using private class data pattern?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, private-members

I used to have this as a `TimeUnit` declaration in a library:

**Solution1:**

```
typedef boost::posix::ptime TimeUnit;

TimeUnit createTimeUnit( int hours, int minutes );
std::string toString( const TimeUnit& timeUnit );
```

Let's say I'd like to move this to something more object-oriented:

**Solution2:**

```
class TimeUnit : public boost::posix::ptime
{
public:
    TimeUnit( int hours, int minutes );

    std::string toString() const;
};
```

And now, let's say I don't want libraries using this class to directly depend on boost, so I'd like to use the private class data pattern, to remove any boost reference from my header file:

**Solution3:**

```
class TimeUnitPrivate;
class TimeUnit
{
public:
    TimeUnit( int hours, int minutes );
    ~TimeUnit();

    std::string toString() const;
public:
    TimeUnitPrivate* m_data;
};
```

`TimeUnitPrivate` being roughly the same as Solution2's `TimeUnit` and the new `TimeUnit` being simply:

```
TimeUnit::TimeUnit( int hours, int minutes ) : 
    m_data( hours, minutes )
{}

TimeUnit::~TimeUnit()
{
    delete m_data;
}

std::string TimeUnit::toString()
{
    return m_data->toString();
}
```

Solution3 is very smart and I'd save compilation time + limit boost dependencies for sure.

**But I was wondering what was the cost of each solution in term of:**

- **Memory usage**. Will the three solutions of TimeUnit objects need the same amount of bytes to be stored in memory? If not, which one is the best (I suppose it's Solution1)
- **Performance**: For sure, Solution3's `toString()` will be slower than Solution2's (as function cannot be inline, there will be an additional function call needed in the end). That's not a big deal. But I'm wondering if object creation/destruction will be slower...how would the three solutions be sorted in term of performance for object creation/destruction?

Comment: I am seeing a number of `std::sting`. Did you mean `std::string` ?

Comment: Allocating `TimeUnitPrivate` and calling functions from it might have a (very minimal) impact about performance.

Comment: BTW, your current solution 3 doesn't respect rule of 3 (or 5)...

Comment: Note also that you have 4th solution with virtual method (with its cost). to hide boost dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two solutions are exactly identical in terms of memory usage and performance. One is just more object-y than the other, purely a matter of preference.

The handle-body/pimpl idiom solution will take more memory (by the size of a pointer) and be slower (an extra indirection with each call, extra allocation on creation). How much slower? You'll have to time it. Does the extra memory usage and performance hit hurt you in comparison to the speedup in compilation time and reduction in dependency? Purely dependent on whatever it is your project is doing. For some applications, performance on that scale doesn't matter in the slightest so it's certainly worth speeding up compilation. For other applications, this would be a complete non-starter. There's no universal answer.

Comment: You're probably right....saving few seconds at compilation is maybe better than saving few nanoseconds during execution....at least in my situation.